# Wrapping certain characters around a tag in vb.net

Tags: .net, vb.net

I am returning a string which contains "1. ~~~~ 2. ~~~~~ 3.~~~~~~"

Using regex i was able to find all numbers then full stop using:

```
([0-9]\.)
```

I am trying to find all these occurances with a number then dot at the beginning, and wrap them with a "`<p>`" & "`</p>`"

as such will contain "`<p>1.</p> ~~~~ <p>2.</p> ~~~~~ <p>3.~~~~~~</p>`"

What i have done so far, but does not work

```
            Dim getLiteratura As String = "1. some text <br /> 2. some text <br /> 3. some text"
            Dim Pattern As String = "/^[0-9]\./gm"
            Dim ReturnedMatches As MatchCollection = Regex.Matches(getLiteratura, Pattern)
            For Each ReturnedMatch As Match In ReturnedMatches
              //here for each occurance wrap p tags around match
               dim sss as string = sss & "<p>" & ReturnedMatch & "</p>"
            Next
```

The above does not seem to work and i am not sure why

Thanks!

Comment: ok and what problem are you facing? You haven't told us what's wrong or asked us a question. A statement of intent doesn't constitute a question.

Comment: apologies, description amended

Comment: Thanks. So..."does not work" means what, precisely? You get an error? Or the result is not what you expected? Please let us know what your code currently outputs. Also it would be a lot easier to follow if the sample code used the same input data as the example you give above it. Then we can expect the same output from it in both cases.

Comment: It does not return anything, if i response.write the string it does not print anything

Comment: So from that, it would seem we can infer that `ReturnedMatches` does not contain any matches, and so it never enters the loop which populates the variable. Have you verified that using your debugger?

Comment: BTW, have you noticed that the regex in your question text is not the same as the regex in your code.

Comment: Yeah i have noticed that, it now outputs the match! thanks! One quick last question, it finds all of the matches but doesnt include any of the other text? So at the moment it outputs "1.2.3." but should contain the other information too.. the "some text"

Comment: @p.developer Could the text ~~~~~ ever include a number? Could it include a number followed by a full stop?

Comment: it could include numbers, but never a number then a full stop

Comment: " at the moment it outputs "1.2.3." but should contain the other information too" the solution to that is to replace the 1. in your original string with the new text. At the moment you just generate a new string containing only the matched data.

Comment: Do the actual items happen to be separated with `<br /> `, as shown in the code in the question?

Answer (score 0):

I am not very comfortable with RegEx but it can be done the old fashioned way.

```
    Dim getLiteratura As String = "1. some text <br /> 2. some text <br /> 3. some text"
    'changing the name of your variable to save space
    Dim s As String = getLiteratura
    Dim newStringBuilder As New StringBuilder
    For index As Integer = 0 To s.Length - 1
        If index = s.Length - 1 Then
            newStringBuilder.Append(s(index))
            Continue For
        End If
        If Char.IsNumber(s(index)) And s(index + 1) = "." Then
            newStringBuilder.Append("<p>" & s(index))
        ElseIf s(index) = "." And Char.IsNumber(s(index - 1)) Then
            newStringBuilder.Append(".</p>)")
        Else
            newStringBuilder.Append(s(index))
        End If
    Next
    Dim newString = newStringBuilder.ToString()
    Debug.Print(newString)
    'Output
    '<p>1.</p>) some text <br /> <p>2.</p>) some text <br /> <p>3.</p>) some text
```